# File Input - Image to Base64 String - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I am trying to create a function in jQuery that will convert an image file from an input field and return a base64 string. Then set the value of a text area.

```
$("#Base_File").change(function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var FR = new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function (e) {
            var basecode = e.target.result;
            $("#Base_Code").val(basecode);
        };
        FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you are facing? If you post your code we might able to help you.

Comment: I just can't seem to get it to work? This is what I have (Not A function). I need to to work for all browsers.

Comment: *"I just can't seem to get it to work"* What is the input and what output are you getting? What output do you expect? If it "doesn't work" I assume you get an error. What is the error? You really have to provide more information (especially your code).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have posted the code above, which works but not in safari for some reason??

Comment: Safari version ? : [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader)

Comment: It seems to work for me in Safari 7: http://jsfiddle.net/5xk8f/.

Comment: Windows 5.1.7 safari, I need it to work in all browsers..

Comment: check the link I gave in the last comment, can't use directly FileReader in safari 5.1

Comment: You cannot use something that doesn't exist. A workaround could ebe to send the file to the server, encode it there and send the result back to the client.

Comment: It will never work like this in _all browsers_ ... maybe you mean _current versions of common browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer and Safari_

Comment: Ahh ok, I will try that, not too good with PHP tho.. I will give it a go and see what I can come up with. Thanks for your help!